# Exception: JNI: Init'd AndroidJavaClass with null ptr

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

I get this error every time. How do i fix it.

```
Exception: JNI: Init'd AndroidJavaClass with null ptr!
UnityEngine.AndroidJavaClass..ctor (IntPtr jclass) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Runtime/Export/AndroidJavaImpl.cs:539)
UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.get_JavaLangClass () (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Runtime/Export/AndroidJavaImpl.cs:517)
UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.FindClass (System.String name) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Runtime/Export/AndroidJavaImpl.cs:508)
UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject._AndroidJavaObject (System.String className, System.Object[] args) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Runtime/Export/AndroidJavaImpl.cs:110)
UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject..ctor (System.String className, System.Object[] args) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/artifacts/EditorGenerated/AndroidJava.cs:17)
AdmobVNTIS.Awake () (at Assets/AdmobVNTIS/AdmobVNTIS.cs:55)
```

And, this error;
I think its a java problem and it have the same solution.

```
Exception: JNI: Init'd AndroidJavaClass with null ptr!
UnityEngine.AndroidJavaClass..ctor (IntPtr jclass) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Runtime/Export/AndroidJavaImpl.cs:539)
UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.get_JavaLangClass () (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Runtime/Export/AndroidJavaImpl.cs:517)
UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.FindClass (System.String name) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Runtime/Export/AndroidJavaImpl.cs:508)
UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject._AndroidJavaObject (System.String className, System.Object[] args) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Runtime/Export/AndroidJavaImpl.cs:110)
UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject..ctor (System.String className, System.Object[] args) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/artifacts/EditorGenerated/AndroidJava.cs:17)
AdmobVNTIS_Interstitial.initializeInterstitial () (at Assets/AdmobVNTIS/AdmobVNTIS_Interstitial.cs:39)
AdmobVNTIS_Interstitial.Awake () (at Assets/AdmobVNTIS/AdmobVNTIS_Interstitial.cs:29)
```

Its like the same error but its a bit different.

My game detail:

i made a basic 2d game hwo just contain ongui function i have added facebook sdk, google ads sdk, i have installed all the android sdk from sdk manager, i have installed admob plugin vntis. but i havent used facebook sdk. and my pc is 64 bit.

Comment: can you show the actual JNI implementation code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error only in Editor. If you want to get rid of it surround your line of code with

```
#if UNITY_ANDROID
    ...
#endif
```

You need an actual android device to run that specific line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
#if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
//do something here
#endif
```

Comment: If you indent the code with four spaces instead of surrounding it with a single backtick (```), you won't get the spaces in between the lines